# Youtube video embedded with iframe not playing hd

Tags: html, ipad, iframe, youtube

I´m making a web page and I have embedded an hd Youtube video with iframe on my html document. It works fine with Chrome and Safari on my MAC but in Firefox and on the Ipad (both in Safari and Chrome) **it only plays the standard video (not the HD version!)**.

Notes: neither `hd=1` or `fmt=22` or `vq=hd720` solved the question. And I´m not using any javascript.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks. Florencia.

**EDIT -- Code from OP's comment:**

```
 <iframe class="fullscreen" id="propiedades" 
   src="youtube.com/embed/nkHGbUyeo2o?feature=player_detailpage&‌modestbranding=1&title=&showinfo=0&hd=1&rel=0&autoplay=1&autohide=1&controls=0&ve‌​rsion=3&wmode=transparent"
   frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen 
   seamless="seamless"> 
 </iframe>
```

Comment: Can you give us some example code of what you've done so far? Perhaps even set up a fiddle?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for your interest! Iím sorry but I don´t know what a fiddle is... but I would be very thankful if you could help me out with this, so here is my simple code:
 <iframe  class="fullscreen" id="propiedades"
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/nkHGbUyeo2o?feature=player_detailpage    &modestbranding=1&title=&showinfo=0&hd=1&rel=0&autoplay=1&autohide=1&controls=0&version=3&wmode=transparent"
frameborder="0"  webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen seamless="seamless">
   </iframe>

Comment: I'll admit, I don't know enough about embedding YouTube (never done it before), but I can give you a couple of questions that may help you figure out where to look.  If you go to "http://youtube.com/html5" and see if one system is running `html5` video and the other is using `flash` video.

Comment: I´ve checked it out and they are all the same. The problem is that when I run the page in firefox and ipad my video is played in a SD (standard -not HD-) version (which I never uploaded). So, it must be the browser who decides which version to play, I think, but I don´t know how to tell to stick to the HD version. Thank you anyway! Florencia.